# How to close the current tab of Internet explorer in vbscript or javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript

I want to close the current tab of Internet explorer on click of 'Log Out' button. It is a new functionality to be implemented in my web application. My application supports only Internet Explorer. The page on which Logout button is located is combination of many pages of window.close() is not working.

I have used following code in vbscript to close the current window of browser for Internet Explorer:

```
 if(window.opener = Empty) then
     dim x
     x = "<%=Request.Browser.MajorVersion%>"

     if(x="6") then
        window.parent.opener = "x"
        window.parent.close
     else  
      'I need code for closing the tab here for IE7
      end if   

  end if
```

I have used "<%=Request.Browser.MajorVersion%>" to fetch the version of Internet explorer. Itf it is IE6 then code works fine because there is no tab functionality in IE6 but how to close the current tab for IE7. Please help me out in this context so that I may close the current tab for IE7 also. Thnaks in advance!

Comment: I think you can only close windows or tabs that you "own" with javascript.  Have you tried setting the window.opener to self, then using window.close()?

Comment: Yes I have tried it by setting window.opener = self...but that didnt worked too :(

Comment: @box86rowh:- I think thats right what you are saying but you can definitely close the tab in IE7 also. I have just posted my answer for that and it is working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to close the tab in IE7:-

```
    window.parent.opener = "x"
    window.parent.close
```

I have faced the same issue and found that this was working fine for me. Although this would give you an extra message(Microsoft warning message):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modern day browsers will not allow you to close a window or tab that you have not created with window.open. Any ways of doing it to make it work is a HACK and is bound to break when browsers are upgraded.

Comment: But my code is working perfectly fine for IE6 but when I am trying to do the same in IE7 it is not responding. I have to implement my code only for IE7.

Comment: IE6/7 - Your company works in the stone ages, nothing like supporting browsers that Microsoft does not even support.

Comment: Sorry but I cant help it but we are dealing with IE6/7 and I have to implement this functionality. Any help would be appreciable. I have seen this functionality happeneing for many sites right now which includes the https://netbanking.rbs.in/BANKAWAY?Action.RetUser.Init.001=Y&AppSignonBankId=ABN&AppType=corporate

Comment: Please refer this link. I want to implement the same functionality but I am not able to do the same. Please see this:- http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/ClosingWindowsNotOpenedByJS-2.html

Comment: @epascarello:- I think what you are saying is perfectly right but we can definitely close the tab in IE7. I have just posted my answer and it is working perfectly fine. Thanks :)